# How to set itemController for instance variable in ember.js indexController?

Tags: ember.js

I have a Ember.js page that displays a table of items and shows details of one of the items when it is selected. The controller looks like this:

```
CV.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: "CurrVitae",

  selectedCurrVitae: false,

  actions: {
    selectCurrVitae: function(currVitae) {
      this.set('selectedCurrVitae', currVitae)
    }
  }
});
```

And the index controller is used in a template like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="curr-vitae-list">
    {{#each curr_vitae in controller}}
      <div class="curr-vitae-item row">
        <div class="col-sm-2" {{action selectCurrVitae curr_vitae}}>
          {{curr_vitae.name}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <!-- NOTE: This method is defined on the item 
               controller (not the model) so the itemController is 
               available at this point. -->
          {{curr_vitae.createdAtDisplay}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
          <div class="embedded-cell">
            {{curr_vitae.summary}}
          </div>
          <div class="embedded-cell">
            {{curr_vitae.objective}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
  <div class="curr-vitae-view">
    <h2>Details</h2>

    <!-- EDIT: I have tried setting this 
         as {{#if selectedCurrVitae itemController="currVitae" }}
         to match the way the #each handles item controllers but that did
         not seem to work -->
    {{#if selectedCurrVitae }}

      <!-- NOTE: Down here, however, the item controller is not available 
           so I can't use methods defined on the item controller for the 
           currently selected instance. -->
      {{ partial "cv_index_details" }}
    {{/if}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Question: The problem I'm running in to is that the `itemController` I've set in the index controller is not available when rendering the `selectedCurrVitae` in the `cv_index_details`.

More details:

Specifically, in the partial I want to reuse a editor component (taken from Noel Rappin's Ember.js book).  So if the `cv_index_details` partial looks like this:

```
<h3 class="selected_cv">{{selectedCurrVitae.name}}</h3>

<div class="row selected_cv_summary">
  <h4>Summary</h4>
  {{block-editor emberObject=selectedCurrVitae propName="summary" action="itemChanged"}}
</div>

<div class="row selected_cv_experiences">
  <h4>Experiences</h4>
  {{#each experience in selectedCurrVitae.experiences itemController="experience"}}
    {{ partial "experience_detail" }}
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

So in this template, the `itemChanged` action is not found for the `selectedCurrVitae` instance. However, I use the same `block-editor` component for the `experience` instance and that works correctly; the `itemChanged` action defined on the `ExperienceController` is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

selectedCurrVitae is outside of the `itemController`, the `itemController` is only applied inside the each (on each item, hence the name).

Probably the easiest way to accomplish this will be to reuse the item controller and use render.

#### Template

```
{{#if selectedCurrVitae }}
  {{ render "cv_index_details" }}
{{/if}}
```

#### Controller

```
CV.CvIndexDetailsController = CV.CurrVitaeController.extend();
```

Or

#### Template

```
{{#if selectedCurrVitae }}
  {{ render "currVitae" }}
{{/if}}
```

#### View

```
CV.CurrVitaeView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'cv_index_details'
});
```

Comment: It seems to be very forgiving. It successfully uses the `itemController` (named "currVitae" or "CurrVitae"; both seen to work) when iterating through the collection. The `createdAtDisplay` method is defined in the item controller and it works either way.

Comment: yup, they've gotten more flexible indeed.

Comment: I assume you're setting selectedCurrVitae to the model somewhere.

Comment: Yes, `selectedCurrVitae` is set using an action on line 5 of the template and stored in the `IndexController` (it's defaulted to `false`--newbie mistake on my part--but it gets set to an instance in that action).

Comment: I'm not aware of an easy way of switching to a specific instance's controller.  It's a little more tricky because you're using a component and when you sendAction it sends it to the controller.

Comment: The way above is probably the easiest way I can think of doing it.

Comment: You set me on the right track, but I ended up adding the action to the index controller since the I needed to reference the `selectedCurrVitae` instance. E.g.  `actions: {  itemChanged: function() { this.get('selectedCurrVitae').save(); } }`